# Django: Can I have two labels for a field?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-crispy-forms

I have a django form and I need to display unit of measurement.

For example, for a form field I have label and value. I also need to have another 'label' for unit measurement.

E.g. **Weight [Textbox] Kg**

How can I add Kg in a form in forms.py? I'm using crispy forms module to render my forms.

This is an example from forms.py .

```
class WeightForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(LifeEventsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper=FormHelper(self)
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
             'weight',

             FormActions(
                Submit('submit', "Save changes"),
                Submit('cancel',"Cancel")
            ),
        )
        self.helper.form_tag = False
        self.helper.form_show_labels = True

class Meta:
    model = myWeight
```

My models.py looks like:

```
class myWeight(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField()
    weight = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

Comment: Something like http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/dynamic_layouts.html#manipulating-a-layout ?

Comment: @TomDalton Thank you! I think this all I need.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not best idea, but pretty straightforward:

You can override `from crispy_forms.layout import Field` with custom template

```
class DoubleLabeledField(Field):
    template = "your_custom_field.html"
```

copypaste to `your_custom_field.html` everything from ...`/site-packages/crispy_forms/templates/bootstrap3/field.html` (replace `bootstrap3` if another template package)  and put some info near every entrance of `{{ field.label|safe }}`

Then in your form should be:

```
self.helper.layout = Layout(
             DoubleLabeledField('weight'),

             FormActions(
                Submit('submit', "Save changes"),
                Submit('cancel',"Cancel")
            ),
        )
```